# Eclipse New Project (From Sample) Defaults to Errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't know much about Java or Android development, so I'm digging into it myself.  But I noticed that if I open sample code that came with my new 2.2 SDK, Eclipse by default will contain errors until I open up specific files.  Is this normal for IDEs?  Or is there something I'm missing?

I am having to use Eclipse 3.5.2 since Google said there is issues with the new version and the 2.2 SDK (or was it the Android Plugin?)

Answer (score 1):

The better way is install once again like following:

download ->http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

download ->http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

And place that in one new folder.
select->\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator.exe (install packages if u need..refresh)

now open the eclipse select help-> install new software... and select "android-sdk-windows"

and before open the eclipse create one new folder to workspace (save projects).

Answer (score 0):

This also seemed to may be a bug in what series of installs I was using and versions. Though updates I now notice no problems what so ever.